# Can I keep playing after the final quest on Fallout 1?

Tags: fallout

I have Fallout 1 and I already beat it, but when I defeated the Master, I got the dialog sequence with the Overseer (when you are expelled from Vault 13) and then game was over (pretty sad, that ending sequence).

I still had some optional quests to do, but I wasn't able to finish those. I'd like to know if, after I beat the final boss, can I continue playing the game and do side quests?

Comment: This should really be asked as two separate questions - they're different games.

Comment: IMOP I don't think this should have been closed.  Yes it would have been better to make two different questions, but I would have left it open since it was two definitive "yes or no" questions.

Comment: @TimmyJim Separate questions should be asked separately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/197289-fallout/50260887), once you finish the main quest, the game is over.

Answer (score 1):

There's a relatively new mod called "Fallout Et Tu" or "Fo1in2" that allows you to continue playing. It's actually a port of the F1 campaign to the F2 engine, and thus it works the same way - when the campaign ends, it asks you if you want to continue playing or not.

Besides this, it also lets you enable various cut content, and make some other adjustments.

- [Fallout Et Tu @ GitHub](https://github.com/rotators/Fo1in2)
- [Fallout Et Tu @ NMA](https://nma-fallout.com/threads/fallout-et-tu-release-v1-8.218045/)